# Do the coefficients $a_{i,j}$ of the Gauss-Legendre method form an invertible matrix?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

The coefficients of the $s$-step Gauss-Legendre method, which is a special case of a generalized Runge-Kutta method, are given by
\begin{equation*}
a_{i,j}=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}(1+\zeta_{i})}\prod_{k=1,k\neq j}^{s}\frac{t-\frac{1}{2}(1+\zeta_{k})}{\frac{1}{2}(\zeta_{j}-\zeta_{k})}dt\text{,}
\end{equation*}
where $\zeta_{k}$ ($k\in\{1,...,s\}$) are the roots of the Legendre polynomial of degree $s$ on $(-1,1)$.

**How do I show that the Matrix $A=(a_{i,j})_{i,j=1}^{s}$ is invertible?**

Comment: You mean the implicit $s$-stage collocation methods with order $2s$, where the $c_i$ are the roots of the Legendre polynomial $P_s(2x-1)$?

Comment: @LutzLehmann yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, one can formulate the method as collocation method using a polynomial $p$ of degree $s$ with
$$
p(0)=0, \\ 
y_n+hp(\tau)\approx y(t_n+h\tau), \\
p'(\tau)\approx y'(t_n+h\tau), ~~\tau\in[0,1].
$$
The step equations are then
$$
k_i=p'(c_i)=f(t_n+c_ih,y_n+hp(c_i)),~~i=1,..,s\\
y_{n+1}=y_n+hp(1).
$$
The relation between the $k_i$ and the coefficients of $p$ is thus linear with a Vandermonde like matrix, which is invertible if the points $c_i$ are all different. This is the case for the Gauss method, as the Legendre polynomial has simple roots. The coefficients $a_{ij}$ are obtained by inverting this relation, giving a likewise invertible matrix.